# Creating a template for work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

Does `TFS 2013` have the ability to automatically add Templated tasks to a work item?
So I create a work item, it automatically adds some tasks for it such as `Code, Test, CodeReview, HelpGuide`

Can you guide me to the right place to read about it if it has this ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in? Then no.

There is an open source TFS Serverside plugin, called TFS Aggregator which will allow you to run a piece of code every time a workitem changes. Creating subtasks when a parent task changes state or is created is a piece of cake.

See:

- https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/releases
- https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Auto-Create-Children

If you don't want to run a server side handler, then you may be able to use a script (powershell can do pretty powerful things when using the Client Object Model).

Or you can use the copy-paste magic of the Excel plugin for TFS. Simply put the tasks you want to create on the clipboard (without an ID) then use the "Insert Rows" paste option to paste them directly under their prospective parent (in a tree based query). Upon publishing the tasks will be associated to the parent. Play with the Title 1, Title 2, Title 3 etc fields to control the nesting.